# What should I write for "Research and Teaching Merits" when applying online for a PhD?

Tags: phd, application

Recently, I want to apply for a PhD position in a place which uses an online system to submit applications. The position is going be filled by either a PhD student or a Postdoc. There is a section in the application form titled "Research and teaching merits" with a mandatory field "Field of research". I wasn't sure what exactly I should write in this field so for now I left a '-' character there.

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find a clear answer about what I should write there. I also contacted the emails provided with the advertisement but there was no response.

What do you think I should write in this field of the application form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the section *Research and Teaching Merits* ought to encompass accomplishments made as a researcher and as a teacher. This could include any distinguished teaching award you might have received in your teaching tenure. If there isn't a separate publication field, you may include your publication here.

As for the field named *Field of research*, this would mean your current domain within the main subject of research. For instance, in Computer Science, fields could be like Machine Learning, Computational Neurosciences, Wireless Sensor Networks, Data Security, etc. Likewise, there would be many specialization areas within Mathematics, Electronics, Instrumentation, Mechanics, and so on.

Comment: Would it make any difference in the meaning of "Field of research" when it is under the section (in the context of) "Research and Teaching Merits"? What do you think?

Comment: @user31387: Well, not much. It just means the field of research in which you state your research merits.